# How to programatically get the product id of newly added product using the commerce form

Tags: commerce

I allow users to create their own products using the default commerce product add form (/admin/commerce/products/add/product). Programatically, I need to get the product ID and do more processing.

I have a submit handler attached like this (I use it to redirect users to a custom page):

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'my_module_redirect_handler';
```

However, I don't seem to have any information about the newly added node. How can I obtain it?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your additional submit handler is invoked after default one (which by looking how you added it, is the case), you can access **nid** of the node created as follows:

```
function my_module_redirect_handler(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $node_id = $form_state['values']['nid'];
}
```

Now that you have **nid** you should be able to do required processing.

Hope that helps.

Comment: All my fields are there but the nid.

Comment: thats strange. did you try the same submit on different content type?I just run that very same script on custom content type and it works

Comment: I've seen this everywhere on the web for non commerce nodes. I did not change anything so it's a bit confusing. I'm temporarily using the EntityFieldQuery to pull the latest product added but this can be an issue when the activity increases.